# jQuery is not working with my form in popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a form inside a popover and use jQuery and Ajax to submit the form(do some calculation while submitting the form). But somehow jQuery is not working at all. I'm using ruby on rails.

Here is my code on the view:

```
    %a.btn.btn-small{:id => "example", "data-toggle" => "popover", :type => "button"}
        %i.icon-calendar
            .head.hide Do Something
            .content.hide
               =form_for :object, action: '#', :html => { :class => "form", remote: true} do |c|
                  =c.number_field :var_1
                  =c.number_field :var_2
               %buttion.btn.btn-default{id: "submit", type: "button"}Click
```

Here is my code in js and jQuery under app/assets/javascript,

```
            $(function () {
              $('#example').popover({ 
                html : true,
                title: function () {
                    return $(this).parent().find('.head').html();
                },
                content: function () {
                    return $(this).parent().find('.content').html();
                }
              }).popover('show');
            });


            $(function(){
                $('.form').submit(function(e) {
                        alert(1);
                    e.preventDefault()
                    var datastring = $(this).serializeArray();
                    datastring.push({name:"post", value:"Post"});

                    var request = $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: $(this).attr('action'),
                        data: datastring});
                        request.success(function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                         })
                });
            });
```

When I click "Click" button, there is even no alert(1) showing up, so i think the jQuery is not working but I can't work out what is going wrong?

Comment: Can you post HTML code instead of server template?

Comment: Check if $('.form') exists before attaching the submit event in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead, this will bind the submit event in ajax loaded content

```
$('body').on('submit', '.form', function(){
  # your code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you follow the best practices then you should be writing jQuery like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('body').on('submit', '.form', function(){
     // your code
  });
});
```